# Unexpected error in mod_passenger: An error occurred while receiving HTTP upload data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am getting error like

```
[ pid=22895 thr=139814677706720 file=ext/apache2/Hooks.cpp:884 time=2013-04-18 21:10:56.113 ]: Unexpected error in mod_passenger: An error occurred while receiving HTTP upload data: End of file found (70014)
  Backtrace:
     in 'boost::shared_ptr<Passenger::BufferedUpload> Hooks::receiveRequestBody(request_rec*)' (Hooks.cpp:1321)
     in 'int Hooks::handleRequest(request_rec*)' (Hooks.cpp:585)
```

Comment: Maybe someone has had your same problem:

you can [give a look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904352/not-able-to-upload-in-a-passenger-app-behing-apache)

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution.

If your server in cantos then change this line in your **httpd.conf**

your httpd.conf file is in **etc/conf/httpd.conf**

Open that file and change this line

default is `KeepAlive is 60`. now change this and `replace 60 to 100.`

Hope this will work in your side.