# Redmine file upload error - Disconnecting client with error: error reading request body: Unexpected end-of-stream (errno=-1004)

Tags: apache, redmine

I am trying to upload large file via Redmine but I get 'error' message in the UI after a while. Apache error logs shows error just after pressing file upload button:

```
[ 2017-08-24 11:18:55.3637 5133/7f34b3fff700 Ser/Server.h:1039 ]: [Client 1-166] Disconnecting client with error: error reading request body: Unexpected end-of-stream (errno=-1004)
[ 2017-08-24 11:19:25.4897 5313/7fe0e052f780 apa/Hooks.cpp:690 ]: Unexpected error in mod_passenger: An error occurred while receiving HTTP upload data: Unknown error -102 (-102)
  Backtrace:
     in 'void Hooks::sendRequestBody(const Passenger::FileDescriptor&, request_rec*, bool)' (Hooks.cpp:1200)
     in 'int Hooks::handleRequest(request_rec*)' (Hooks.cpp:561)

[ 2017-08-24 11:19:25.4900 5133/7f34b2ffd700 Ser/Server.h:1039 ]: [Client 3-186] Disconnecting client with error: error reading request body: Unexpected end-of-stream (errno=-1004)
```

Redmine Maximum attachment size is higher than the file size. I have increased Apache `Timeout`, `KeepAliveTimeout`, set `KeepAlive Off` but it didn't help.

There are similar issues:

- [Unexpected error in mod_passenger: An error occurred while receiving HTTP upload data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16084141/unexpected-error-in-mod-passenger-an-error-occurred-while-receiving-http-upload)
- [Not able to upload in a passenger app behing apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904352/not-able-to-upload-in-a-passenger-app-behing-apache)

How to upload large file via Redmine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed `LimitRequestBody` from Apache configuration. Didn't change other properties.